# Linq query with a join and a where clause giving an error

Tags: c#, linq

What am i doing wrong with this Linq query?

The sql statement is :

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    ReportGroups rg INNER JOIN ReportDefinitions rd on rg.ReportGroupID = rd.ReportGroupID
WHERE 
    rd.ReportGroupID = 5
```

LINQ:

```
var query = from rg in ReportGroups  
                join rd in ReportDefinitions on rg.ReportGroupID equals rd.ReportGroupID
                .Where rd.ReportGroupID equals 5
                 select new
                {
                    rg.ReportGroupName, 
                    rd.ReportName
                };

    query.Dump();
```

Comment: use a  where and   ==     , there are variations of the where that are allowed but that should work for you

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing query comprehension syntax with method call syntax. Try replacing `.Where` with `where`.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 mistakes in your query.

First of all use `where` instead of `.Where`.

Secondly in the `where` clause don't use `equals` use `==`, `equals` is used for `joins` only

Like this:

```
var query = from rg in ReportGroups  
                join rd in ReportDefinitions on rg.ReportGroupID equals rd.ReportGroupID
                where rd.ReportGroupID == 5 //updates here
                 select new
                {
                    rg.ReportGroupName, 
                    rd.ReportName
                };

    query.Dump();
```